# How to creat Schedule field to CMS block Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to create a module to set schedule display for CMS Block in Magento 2. Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: Explain your requirement in details.

Comment: Examle: this is default block https://i.imgur.com/7mZb3ej.png
I want it can set time display look like this: https://i.imgur.com/S3hkk7I.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to follow these steps:

1. Create custom module in `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName`
2. Make your module load after `Magento_Cms` module ([modules sequence](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html#examples))
3. Add new columns to the `cms_block` table ([via db_schema](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html))
4. Extend `Magento_Cms` module's base adminhtml views in your module

To do so you need to follow these structure:

1. Create `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_form.xml`
2. Paste this template in the `cms_block_form.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="from_date" sortOrder="11" formElement="date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="validate-date" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">From Date</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <dataScope>from_date</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="until_date" sortOrder="12" formElement="date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="validate-date" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Until Date</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <dataScope>until_date</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

After that you will see new datepicker fields in the block form:
[image: Screenshot with result]